# Button click on every single tooth...Making a layout that works for all screen resolutions

Tags: android, xml, layout, onclicklistener

I have a jaw image as shown,,,i want that on every single tooth, there is a listener and succeded with that by adding button to every single tooth image by the relative layout but it works fine on one screen but gets disordered on the other.. how can i make it to work on all screen sizes[?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoCkU.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out [this](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap), similar case.

**Best of luck**

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/) article, I think the solution it presents suits your scenario well. Instead of solving this with some Android layout wizardry, you can specify a mask for your jaw-image that defines the clickable regions.